# How do I upload my nextjs website to siteground hosting?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hosting

I already have a .next folder with my app built but I would like to know how do I upload it and get it live on siteground

I have used vercel and it was pretty awesome but this is a requirement of a client and I would like to know if it’s possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).